# HttpClient posting large data to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC controller method which make a post call to a WebApi. Bellow my MVC controller method:

```
public async Task<string> PostAdminUploadData()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    var docRepo = new DocRepoViewModel() { CategoryName = "Foo", Roles= "role1" };
    var attachmentInfo = new List<AttachmentViewModel>() { AttachmentName = "Bar", AttachmentType = "Baz", AttachmentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\aa.mp3" };

    //File.ReadAllBytes("c:\aa.mp3" }; if the file size is more than 3Mb

    docRepo.AttachmentInfo = attachmentInfo;
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string uri = 'localhost:8080/api/';
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync('DocRepoApi/PostDoc', docRepo);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
    return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>());
}
```

My WebApi method signature is `public HttpResponseMessage PostDocument(DocRepoViewModel docRepo)`. In the above code I am sending a file and some strings to WebApi. If I try to send a file less than 3MB(approximate max value) my api responds with `200` code and file bytes got saved in DB but if I try with file size something near 3mb or more the api returns `500` code, I got bellow message:

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcQXJjaGl2ZVxDT0VcbmV3X3dzMFxkZXZcQ29tcGV0ZW5jeVxhcGlcRG9jUmVwb0FwaVxQb3N0RG9jdW1lbnQ=?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 06:09:47 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 656
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

Please help to fix this and please provide a expatiation.

Comment: Have you set the content length? Also try to switch off the custom error in web.config to see the actual error.

Comment: @NMK I'm sending the file size. In web.config I have added `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` but same `statusCode` as above

Comment: Have you tried searching for `web api maximum request size`? And maybe looked at results such as [this one](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)? (I'm not saying it'll 100% solve your issue, but have you tried applying some basic problem solving here - if so, which fixes have you already applied?)